# Replace element value in XML file with value from CSV

Tags: xml, csv, powershell

Hello beatiful minds of Stackoverflow.
I'm using powershell to replace values (names) in an XML with fake names from a CSV.
I've got two files, Real.xml (in element style) and Fake.csv.
Real.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Node1>
    <Node2>
      <Element1>blahblahblah</Element1>
      <Element2>blahbablahba</Element2>
      <Node3>
        <Node4>
          <ElementIWannaChange>Cena, John</ElementIWannaChange>
          <Element4>2016-02-11T09:04:15</Element4>
        </Node4>
      </Node3>
    </Node2>
  </Node1>
</Data>
```

Fake.csv looks like this:

```
ID,Fake_first_name,Fake_last_name,First_Name,LastName
16,Sommer,Agar,John,Cena
13,Steve,Hanson,Ben,Cook
103,Bill,Nye,Lynley,Dove
```

The end result I would like is that the powershell will go through the XML replacing the real names in  with the corresponding fake names from the CSV. Example given the data above, Cena, John would be replaced with Agar, Sommer.

This is what I've got thus far.

```
#This script takes the contents of the XML and exchanges the names in order that they appear with names from a CSV in the order that they appear.

#XML
$XMLpath = "D:\Temp\Real.xml"
$XMLnewPath = "D:\Temp\Replaced-Real.xml"
$XMLcontents = [XML] (Get-content $XMLpath)
$Node = $XMLcontents.SelectNodes("/Data/Node1/Node2/Node3/Node4/ElementIWannaChange")

#CSV
$CSVpath = "D:\Temp\Fake.csv"
$CSVcontents = Import-Csv $CSVpath

$i = 0

foreach($individual in $Node)
{
    $field2 = $CSVcontents[$i].first_name
    $field3 = $CSVcontents[$i].last_name
    $individual.'#Text' = "$field3, $field2"
    $i++
}
$XMLcontents.Save($XMLnewPath)
```

Comment: Then add the script you have... This question is currently a request, not a question to solve a problem.

Comment: Aren't the samples mixed up here? `Fake_first_name` in csv equals a value in the "real" xml. Shouldn't the xml have `Cena, John`?

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry have updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop + index won't help here as it would only place a random name on a line. If you have a specific fake name per real name then you need to search for the match each time:

```
#XML
$XMLpath = "D:\Temp\Real.xml"
$XMLnewPath = "D:\Temp\Replaced-Real.xml"
$XMLcontents = [XML] (Get-content $XMLpath)
$Node = $XMLcontents.SelectNodes("/Data/Node1/Node2/Node3/Node4/ElementIWannaChange")

#CSV
$CSVpath = "D:\Temp\Fake.csv"
$CSVcontents = Import-Csv $CSVpath


foreach($individual in $Node)
{
    $last, $first = $individual.'#text' -split ','

    $csvitem = $CSVcontents | Where-Object { ($_.First_Name -eq $first.Trim()) -and ($_.LastName -eq $last.Trim()) }
    if($csvitem) {
        $fakefirst = $csvitem.fake_first_name
        $fakelast = $csvitem.fake_last_name
        $individual.'#Text' = "$fakelast, $fakefirst"
    }

    #Just be sure we don't get false positives because it remembered the last match
    $csvitem = $null
}

$XMLcontents.Save($XMLnewPath)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!